# Is there any inbuilt function in django to clean the data in a request.POST dictionary key?

Tags: html, django

All the inbuilt cleaning methods seem to be only for the Django Forms. I find editing the style of those forms complex and that's why I just prefer create traditional HTML forms and later supply the data from request.POST to the required Django Model. Is there any inbuilt workaround for cleaning such data in Django or I'll have to write a function myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML forms and Django forms together. All you need to do is set the `name` attribute to the name of the field in Django Forms, the rest will just fall in place.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField()
    ...
```

In your HTML form, use

```
<input type="text" name="field1"/>
```